# How do I specify external java source files using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

For example suppose my main Scala project is:

```
c:\code\mainproject
```

There is some other java code I need in a separate project

```
c:\code\secondproject
```

How can a specify this in the lite version of the configuration file? I have tried

```
unmanagedClasspath  += "C:/code/secondproject"
```

However it does not even run

Comment: Did you try adding to "unmanaged-sources" instead of unmanaged classpath?

Answer (score 1):

If the projects are separate, you should publish the second project locally, add that local repository to the first project (or, more generally, to SBT configuration), and then add the project as a normal dependency.